# Getting tsc to allow assigning variables to window

Tags: javascript, node.js, tsc

I'm using `tsc` to validate some Node.js code that's meant to run in the browser.

I want to be able to assign some variables to the global `window` variable, but `tsc` complains:

```
Property 'Blah' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

Normally, I like this type of check, but is there some way to disable it just for `window`? The property check options in `tsconfig.json` either seem to be all or nothing.

Alternatively, is there some way to keep the check, but simply declare these variables in a way `tsc` likes? I'm not using Typescript, so the syntax must be standard Javascript, and all the solutions I've found that were suggested for fixing this error are in Typescript.

Comment: Do you really need to assign `window` properties? Better declare global variables with `var`.

Comment: If you already use `tsc`, why not just use TypeScript to declare these? You can use separate `.d.ts` files afaik.

Comment: @Bergi It's so I can expose certain data and objects to code in <script> tags that otherwise can't interact with Node.js internals.